# xparse can't insert \multicolumn

Tags: tables, macros, multicolumn, xparse

When I try to insert a `\multicolumn` with a macro created using `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand`, I get a `Misplaced \omit` error. When I define the "same" command using `\def`, every thing works fine.

How come? Can I work around this somehow?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

% This definition does not work.
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{}{%
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{asdf}%
}

% This one does.
%\def\foo{%
% \multicolumn{1}{c}{asdf}%
%}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c }
  \foo
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand` defines the macro as robust, you can use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\multicolumn` should be the first thing in a cell (after macro expansion). With `\NewDocumentCommand` this is not possible.

You need

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{asdf}}
```